# Trucrypt still present after clean install of os?

Tags: truecrypt

I completely flattend my laptop but trucrypt is still there on boot up the only way I can get it to boot not windows is by pressing the esc key..

How do I fix the bootloader so I don't have to press escape?

Trucrypt is not in programs so must be stuck somehow in the boot loader am I along the right lines?

Comment: As @Karan mentioned on my reply, which version of Windows do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truecrypt adds to your boot loader (i.e. goes through theirs first).  So it is installed to your MBR, generally.

**In XP/Vista:**

1. Launch a `CMD` as an administrator
2. Try the command `fixmbr`

**In 7:**

1. During Windows boot, hit <kbd>F8</kbd> a bunch.
2. Choose `Repair Your Computer`
3. Let it do its thing, then select `Command Prompt`
4. Use `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

**7 (alt)**:

1. Basically do the above, but use the Windows Install Disc rather than <kbd>F8</kbd>

(Not experienced this with W8, but if you have it - I can do a search for you).

Source:

I used to have truecrypt with the same issue.

Comment: What makes you think he's using Vista?

Comment: Thank you very much so I wouldn't need recovery disk for xp just straight onto operating system, cmd and fixed? Nice and easy